# Find the self-adjoint form of the ODE : $ x^2y''+xy'+\mu y=0 \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the self-adjoint form of the ODE : $ x^2y''+xy'+\mu y=0 \ $ in the form

$ \frac{d}{dx} [p_0 (x) y']+ \mu [q_0(x)]y=0 \ $

**Answer:**

The adjoint equation is

$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2y)-\frac{d}{dx}(xy)+\mu y=0 \\ or, \ (2y+2xy'+x^2y''+2xy)-y-xy'+\mu y=0 \\ or, \ x^2 y''+(2x-x)y'+(1+ \mu+2x)y=0 $

**But how can I put it in the above form given in the question ?**

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $x$ and find
$$
(xy'(x))'+\frac{μ}{x}y(x)=0.
$$
In general, you compute the derivatives in the self-adjoint form and then compare coefficients,
$$
(py')'+qy=py''+p'y'+qy
$$
so that for the one equation to be a multiple of the other, one needs to have $$
\frac{p(x)}{x^2}=\frac{p'(x)}{x},
$$
which again solves to $p(x)=cx$ where you can take $c=1$.

Comment: that means $ p_0(x)=x \ \ and \ \ q_0(x)=\frac{1}{x} \ $

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y''+xy'+\mu y=0$$
$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')=x^2y''+2xy'\quad\to\quad x^2y''=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')-2xy'$
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')-2xy`\right)+xy'+\mu y=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')-xy`+\mu y=0$$
$\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=xy'+y\quad\to\quad xy'=\frac{d}{dx}(xy)-y$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')-\left(\frac{d}{dx}(xy)-y \right)+\mu y=0$$
$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y')-\frac{d}{dx}(xy) +(1+\mu) y=0$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y'-xy) +(1+\mu) y=0$$